# Image from Internet to AppEngine BlobStore (Java)

Tags: java, google-app-engine

I have uploading of pictures in an appengine application. Pictures was saved in blobstore. It uses the html input file.

In addition to that, I want to allow users to save pictures from the internet to the blobstore. If the user have url of a valid picture, I want the picture to be save in blobstore. Is it possible? How to implement this functionality?

e.g. The user will just input url ex. http://domain.com/picture001.jpg then image will be stored in blobstore. Not just the url the picture itself.

Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use [URLFetch](https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/python/urlfetch/) to retrieve the image bytes and then use the [Files API](https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/python/blobstore/overview#Writing_Files_to_the_Blobstore) to write the bytes you fetched to the blobstore.